# Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 Sprint Burndown report not showing To Do tasks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

Why is the Sprint Burndown report not showing To Do tasks?

I'm not seeing anything in the Sprint Burndown report for the current sprint.

Nearly all Tasks have State of To Do. and all have estimates.
All the Task also have Iteration set to the current sprint.
The Sprint is also setup to start today.

The previous sprint currently shows the Done items only and not the To Dos but this could be correct (but this does prove that the reports are picking up some data)

Comment: If I remember correctly it will pick up tasks only after th efirst day has passed. So at the start of a sprint, the burndown doesn't look right, it's the day after that things start working. That, or the fact that the warehouse only updates once in a (configurable) while.

Comment: your on the ball jesse, something like that is what has happened. I can see the data now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sprint burndown will show all work finished before the start of the current day and thus won't show tasks that were added to the sprint on the day that they were added. Just wait until tomorrow and they should show up magically.